# Azure Key Vault - unable to find/select Front Door as Principle for access policy

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-front-door

I'm following this tutorial to use a custom SSL certificate in Front Door from Key Vault ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain-https

... it states that "**In Select principal, search for ad0e1c7e-6d38-4ba4-9efd-0bc77ba9f037, and select Microsoft.Azure.Frontdoor**"

However, when adding the access policy **neither that GUID or "FrontDoor" is in the list** ...

[image: key vault front door missing from access policy]

Any ideas on how to fix this? I need to give Front Door an ssl certificate for an apex domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

> To add the custom domain and name  we need the keyvault

For that I have created the keyvault while creating I have followed the below steps

Azure front door import custom certified only from the keyvault

First I have registered the azure front door service principal using the below script

```
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId “XXXXXXXXXXX”
```

[image]

Go-TO *Portal* **→** search for *Keyvault* **→** create new *keyvault* In the first page give the *name* & *region*
click on next to go to the access policy to new policy

> In the certificate permissions select get , in the secret get & list & authorities

[image]

> When I click on principal  I am able to see ***azure front door***  in the list as shown

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post Komali...

Turns out I forgot to registered the azure front door service principal ... doing that fixed it for me :)

Have a great day!